# database supports multiple data items for a single key

Tags: database, key-value

I need a key/value database. In such a way that I can keep a list of values for each key.

I need database supports multiple data items for a single key.

Comment: This question seems off topic - asking for a recommendation for a software product. Also, please provide _much_ more context - what are some examples of the data you want to store? How much data? What have you considered, and what criteria would define "good"?

Answer (score 2):

As noted, this is possible with almost *any* database.  Posting this answer as it is a surprisingly common question, in order to show that *this cannot be a driving force in selecting a database*.

## SQL

This can be done in any SQL database, often in multiple ways.

### Non-unique indexes

Create a relation `<key, value>`, place a non-unique index on `key`.  Now select all values for a key with e.g.

```sql
SELECT value FROM table WHERE key=...
```

Multiple values are efficiently returned.  For many cases this is more than enough.

Don't overlook `JOIN`ing this table with another table, if some values for a key are repeated and others are not!

### Arrays

SQL supports `ARRAY`s.  You can create a relation with a unique key and a value that is an array.  As always, the PostgreSQL manual section "[Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/arrays.html)" is a great introduction to what you may do with arrays (also for other SQL databases).

### Other data structures in your values

Most SQL databases support many other container data types.  E.g. you might look at the PostgreSQL `jsonb` type; it allows you to keep full-fledged JSON objects as values, search and index on their fields, etc.  This gives an experience more like a document ("no-SQL") database, if this is what you need (or seek).

### Which to choose?

Make your decision based on other requirements.  In other words, you will need more information in order to decide.  Non-unique keys are -- surprisingly -- often the most performant and easiest to use.  Among other things, having each repeated value for a key in its own record allows for easy safe concurrent access.  Choose arrays if you need easy atomic operations across *all* the values for a key -- a much less common requirement.

## NoSQL

A "noSQL" database generally requires a unique key.  Most of them store *document* values, usually a JSON or similar data type.  If your values are contained in an array, you can easily access that array.

A tip: It is generally an *antipattern* to store the array as the entire object.  Prefer instead to keep an array as a field.  For instance, a value might look like:

```json
{
    "key": ...,
    "value": {
        "some-words": ["the", "quick", "brown", "fox"]
    }
}
```

For many people, noSQL databases are a convenient way to solve this requirement because you can sometimes get away with less detailed schema design up-front.
Note, however, that updating a single element of such an array can be painful in many such databases.  Always ensure the update is atomic.  Prefer to use an update or conditional operation.

### Which to choose?

As above: make your decision based on other requirements.  In other words, you will still need more information in order to decide.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be a perfect fit for your use case, but give a look to Redis or any Key-Value in Memory database (RabbitMQ, Memcached).

Otherwise, NoSQL is the way to go having the `id` column as your key and the content whatever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 possibilities:

1. Use a relational database

The table would have a unique composite key based on 2 fields. One is your key the other is a sequence number. You are then able to get all rows with a key.

2. Use a No SQL database

The key is your key. The value is a json document containing all data items connected to that key.

Comment: No need for a composite here. If you also need a unique key for each value, use an auto-increment int for that.